# Anyway to make blue light filter App include the notification swipe-down area?

Tags: applications, 8.0-oreo, operating-system

From initial Googling it seems that it's an intentional issue in later Android OS versions, that blue light filters (Apps) cannot have any effect on the swipe down notification area. I was just wondering if there's any latest news or fixes on this?

For Android OS 8, non-rooted phone.

Comment: Are you referring to the blue light filter functionality in the OS or are you talking about an app providing the blue filter?

Comment: @Robert an App. Added to question

Comment: AFAIR Android 9 includes a system option for reducing blue light. Therefore on Android 9 there is need to use an app for that anymore.

Comment: The following article explains the background and that this restriction is present since Android 8 and will not be changed: https://www.xda-developers.com/android-o-is-breaking-apps-that-overlay-on-top-of-the-status-bar/

Comment: @Robert I have Android OS 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution which can be ised with Moto devices that have Moto Actions. One of the features is Night Display, which is a built-in blue-light filter **which covers the swipe-down notification area.**